# Debugging Data Binding in Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, data-binding

I'm getting alot of issues lately in a project im working on with databinding. When im about to display a certain form that has bindings inside its controls, the .Show method throws expcetions regarding the binding - "Cannot bind to property or column on datasource. Parameter name: dataMember.".

Now, I'm quite aware this is a rather generic error message, but i can't find a decent way to get any info on which binding failed, which control, which data source/member and so on.

Is there a good way to find this?

Comment: The error message isn't that generic, its telling you to take a look at the column in your datasource that is named in your DataMember property of one of your controls.

You might have a data type mismatch, or it could be as simple as the column/property being misspelt in the DataMember property.

Comment: That's the thing, i'm not sure which from the couple dozens of bindings i have to look at, and i have no information on which from the error.

Comment: Where do you see the exception? Are you simply catching it on a higher level? Otherwise turn on break on exception (see my answer).

Comment: It gets thrown on the Form.Show() call even when all exception throwing is enabled, as said.
As said in the newest reply here, Removing the Form/Control's inhertience of IEnumrable 'solves' the problem. I didn't need the inheritence, so thats fine, but the fact the BINDING fails because of it is just odd.

Answer (score 2):

I guess some general debugging tips will help:

When debugging, is there an inner exception with more information?

Another tip is to turn on 'Show external code' in the stack trace window. This will allow you to go further down into the stack to the .Net Framework code itself. Turn on your locals window for information on the content of the current context, this might lead you to the problem.

Also be sure to turn on 'Break on exception' for all CLR exceptions.

Good luck.

Comment: Break on exception might be the winner here, because you'll be able to  look in the autos / locals window to see the control, datasource and data member

Comment: No inner exception or any useful infromation from the thrown ArgumentException. Breaking on all CLR exceptions is enabled, and it doesn't seem to change much.

I'll try the 'Show External code' option if its not already on.

So far, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm stumped. One of the controls in the form is a UserControl i made, Which contains some bindings in it.

This used to work fine. Now, I've added inhertience from IEnumerable to my control so it can return certain objects inside it for a different feature i tried adding. Now, If i 'Step-Into' the .Show call, I reach the IEnumrable implementation i made in a certain case.

Although it returned an empty collection at this time, since i had no elements to return, That apparently caused the ArgumentException that i got with the DataBinding for some reason. The moment i remove the IEnumrable inheritence from my control, Everything is back to normal.

I'm completely clueless as to why this happened.